# Qt How to compare a text from textEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qstring, qtextedit

I have two `QTextEdit` objects. In my first `QTextEdit` object, I have set the text. In my second `QTextEdit` object, I have to type in the text.

I want to compare the two texts something like this:

```
if(ui->textEdit2->toPlainText() == ui->textEdit1->???)
```

My problem is that I don't know which method to use.

Comment: @Andrew Medico : Sorry, I did this accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(ui->textEdit2->toPlainText() == ui->textEdit1->toPlainText())
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: My problem is that I don't know which function I need to use....

I am not entirely sure what makes you think this would require a different method call than for your other `textEdit2. You have at least two ways to achieve this depending on your need.

The first variant would be to simply use the same method call for `textEdit1` as the for `textEdit2`, namely:

```
if (ui->textEdit1->toPlainText() == ui->textEdit2->toPlainText())
```

Note that I swapped the order as I think it reads better and it is more comprehensive that way. It may be just my personal style, so pardon me.

If you would like to do case insensitive comparison, then you could also write the following using the [static compare method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#compare) of the `QString` class.

```
if (!QString::compare(ui->textEdit1->toPlainText(), ui->textEdit2->toPlainText(), Qt::CaseInsensitive))
```

The first solution would be too limited to do a case insensitive comparison, so pick your solution based on your exact desire.